# using render_to_string library is not working

Tags: jquery, django, render-to-string

i have a django code that allow user to add books to a list with javascript function that handle an ajax request once the user click the button. i am using BootStrap 4

the problem is that once the user click the button the console  display the below error :

> File "C:\Users\LTGM~1\Desktop\CRUDDJ~1\env\lib\site-packages\widget_tweaks\templatetags\widget_tweaks.py", line 163, in render_field
>       raise TemplateSyntaxError(error_msg + ": %s" % pair)
>   django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: 'render_field' tag requires a form field followed by a list of attributes and values in the form attr="value": class

## urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from .views import *

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('books/',book_list, name = "book_list"),
    path('books/create/',book_create, name = "book_create"),
]
```

## views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from books.models import Book
from books.forms import BookForm
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.template.loader import render_to_string

def book_list(request):
    books = Book.objects.all()#list all records
    return render(request, './book_list.html',{'books':books})


def book_create(request):
    form = BookForm()
    context= {'form':form}
    html_form = render_to_string('./partial_book_create.html',context,request=request,)
    return JsonResponse({'html_form':html_form})
```

## partial_book_create.html

```
{% load widget_tweaks %}

<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-lable="Close">
            <span aria-hidden = "true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Create a new book</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        {% for field in form %}
            <div class="form-group{% if field.errors %} has-error{% endif %}">
                <label for ="{{ field.id_for_lable }}">{{ field.lable }}</label>
                {% render_field field class ="form-control" %}
                {% for error in field.errors %}
                    <p class="help-block">{{ error }}</p>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="buuton" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create book</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

## books.js

```
$(function(){
    $(".js-create-book").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url:"/books/create/",
            type:"get",
            dataType:"json",
            beforeSend:function(){
                $("#modal-book").modal("show");
            },
            success: function(data){
                $("#modal-book .modal-content").html(data.html_form);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

i did not understand what is and how to fix the error

i am new to the  **widget_tweaks**  and to **render_to_string**

i will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra space before the `=` in your render_field tag.

```
{% render_field field class="form-control" %}
```

Comment: this was the error thank you sorry for this question if it seams stupid